# Save select option form to cookie

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

Help!!

Been trying to figure out how can i save a value of select form in a specific cookie, 
i tried the code that was posted on this, it works but thus gives me a new cookie name, what i need is to save it to a existing cookie

this is the code

```
<div class="form_location">
            <form method="post" action="#">
<select name="cities" class="location">
<option value=""></option>
option value="aber">Aberdeen </option>
<option value="bakingstone">Bakingstoke </option>
<option value="bath">Bath </option>
</form> 
</div>

$fb(document).ready(function() {                                                                                  
var selectbox=$fb('.form_location').find('.location'), selectboxCookieName='$_COOKIE("gmw_city")';
selectbox.each(function(){
 $fb(this).prop('value', $fb.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name));
 });
 selectbox.change(function(){
if(this.value){
  $fb('.city').text($fb(this).val());
 $fb.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name, this.value,{
   expires: 365
 });
 }else{
 $fb.removeCookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name);
        }

    });                 
});
```

how can i save this to my cookie that has name 'gmw_city'

thanks in advance

Comment: You might try this jquery plugin instead - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: hi donal, thanks for the quick reply! what im trying to do is to save the value of select option to the cookie pulled out from a plugin..The default value of the cookie is the location of the user, and when the user select to other location on select box, the value of the cookie will change, hope i'm making sense..